# Injecting parametrs in provider with ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, parameter-passing, ninject

I'm using a provider to instantiate the class used when backing my interface like this:

```
        Bind<IFoo>()
            .ToProvider<FooProvider>()
            .InSingletonScope();
```

How do I go about passing an argument into the providers constructor/CreateInstance-method?

Is there something wrong with my approach? Fairly new to DI-frameworks in general.

Answer (score 0):

The binding is generally ok, `FooProvider` will be instanciated by ninject - so you can pass in anything you want. If you need to pass values to the ctor of `FooProvider` you can either bind the dependencies or customize the binding for `FooProvider` to pass in the arguments:

```
kernel.Bind<FooProvider>().ToSelf()
      // will match a parameter of type `int`
      .WithConstructorArgument<int>(15)
      // will match a parameter with name `parameterName`
      .WithConstructorArgument("parameterName", "parameterValue");
```

If you want to pass a parameter to the `Create(IContext context)` method of the `Provider` then a provider is most likely not the right thing to go with, instead have a look at the abstract factory pattern and [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory) (both are covered by other questions / answeres here on SO).